# Sticky Navigation 8.x-1.1. Funny padding-top

Tags: navigation

In in Drupal 8.5 Theme Bartik and using the Sticky Navigation 8.x-1.1.
When by any chance I reload a page of my site and at that moment I’m positioned in the middle of that page and the menu is “sticky”,  the module add a padding-top equal to the height of the sticky menu bar to the tag Body (as an inline styling). If you go up to the top of the page, after reloading, there is a white strip at the very top of the page (originated by the padding top). Can some tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far my solution was to apply CSS + jQuery to me theme:

CSS

```
body.js--padding-fix {
   padding-top:0 !important;
}
```

and JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery('div.primary-menu-container-global').hasClass('stickynav-active')) 
    {
        jQuery('body').addClass('js--padding-fix'); 
    }     
});
```

Note: if you apply the CSS directly to the body tag, it creates a problem with the Admin Menu, that covers the top of the site (minimized this way)

Is there a better solution?